# Sort SWT table on cell text

Tags: swt, jface

I have an SWT `Table` which I use with a JFace `TableViewer`.

I want to have the table sorted with a comparator that works with the **text in the table cells**, not with the model elements in the viewer.

Is that any good way to do this?

#### Motivation

I'm trying to do this because sorting a table on the cell text works in almost all cases, and it saves me from having to create separate comparators for each model object property that I want to be able to sort on.

---

#### Details

The problem is tables are normally sorted using a `ViewerComparator` set on the viewer. Its `compare` method does not have access to the position in the table of its argument elements:

```java
new ViewerComparator() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Viewer viewer, Object elem1, Object elem2) {
        // There seems to be no good way to get the 
        // text of the table cells here
    }
}
```

---

#### Bad solutions I have considered

- Looking up the cell widget in `ViewerComparator#compare` using `StructuredViewer#findItem`. This probably works, but I have to sub-class all viewers to make that method public.
- Translating the compared elements into strings using the label provider in `ViewerComparator#compare`. This does not work, since most label providers I use are `CellLabelProvider`, and I don't find a way to call `update` on them to get the table text.

Comment: You would normally just call `getText` on the label provider.

Comment: @greg: But if the label provider is a `CellLabelProvider`?

Comment: You can always make the cell label provider implement `ILabelProvider` as well to give you a `getText`. You could look at the `getTextFromLabelProvider` method of `org.eclipse.e4.ui.dialogs.filteredtree.PatternFilter` which has a similar problem

Comment: That works I guess. But it's not as general as I hoped. I'd like my sorter to work with any table viewer and label provider, without having to do anything special with them.

Answer (score 1):

You could make your cell label provider implement `ILabelProvider` so that it has a `getText` method.

You could look at the `getTextFromLabelProvider` method of `org.eclipse.e4.ui.dialogs.filteredtree.PatternFilter` which has a similar problem:

```java
private String getTextFromLabelProvider(IBaseLabelProvider baseLabelProvider, Object element) {
    if (baseLabelProvider == null) {
        return null;
    }
    String labelText = null;
    if (baseLabelProvider instanceof ILabelProvider) {
        labelText = ((ILabelProvider) baseLabelProvider).getText(element);
    } else if (baseLabelProvider instanceof IStyledLabelProvider) {
        labelText = ((IStyledLabelProvider) baseLabelProvider).getStyledText(element).getString();
    } else if (baseLabelProvider instanceof DelegatingStyledCellLabelProvider) {
        IStyledLabelProvider styledStringProvider = ((DelegatingStyledCellLabelProvider) baseLabelProvider)
                .getStyledStringProvider();
        StyledString styledText = styledStringProvider.getStyledText(element);
        if (styledText != null) {
            labelText = styledText.getString();
        }
    }

    return labelText;
}
```

Comment: This code does not work with `CellLabelProvider`s that are not `DelegatingStyledCellLabelProvider` it seems?

Comment: There isn't any way to make that work. You would have to change the provider to implement `ILabelProvider` or one of the other interface.